# Android databinding and LiveData: Can't bind to value in LiveData property

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm trying out databinding for a view that's supposed to display data exposed through a LiveData property in a viewmodel, but I've found no way to bind the object inside the LiveData to the view. From the XML I only have access to the value property of the LiveData instance, but not the object inside it. Am I missing something or isn't that possible?

My ViewModel:

```
class TaskViewModel @Inject
internal constructor(private val taskInteractor: taskInteractor)
    : ViewModel(), TaskContract.ViewModel {

    override val selected = MutableLiveData<Task>()
    val task: LiveData<Task> = Transformations.switchMap(
        selected
    ) { item ->
        taskInteractor
            .getTaskLiveData(item.task.UID)
    }
    ... left out for breivety ... 
}
```

I'm trying to bind the values of the task object inside my view, but when trying to set the values of my task inside my view I can only do `android:text="@={viewmodel.task.value}"`. I have no access to the fields of my task object. What's the trick to extract the values of your object inside a LiveData object?

My task class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "tasks")
data class Task(val id: String, 
                val title: String, 
                val description: String?, 
                created: Date, 
                updated: Date, 
                assigned: String?)
```

Comment: why are you using two way binding for TextView

Comment: Because I want to save changes made to the task, whenever the user makes changes to the task in the UI.

Comment: Then you have a problem with `task` not being mutable in any case.

Comment: @tynn Will it only work if task is mutable?

Comment: you have to observe your live data variable inside fragment in order to get the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why are you using two way binding for TextView 
`android:text="@={viewmodel.task.value}"`
instead use like this  `android:text="@{viewmodel.task.title}"`

Comment: Doesn't solve my problem. Still can't access the fields of my task.

Comment: please use some values inside the task model instead of the whole value i.e., 
    android:text="@{viewmodel.task.title}"

Comment: This finally worked after some tweaks. Also people should be aware that the IntelliJ code completion can create problems, as it doesn't make suggestions for the fields of the livedata object.

Answer (score 26):

For `LiveData` to work with *Android Data Binding*, you have to set the `LifecycleOwner` for the binding

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

and use the `LiveData` as if it was an `ObservableField`

```
android:text="@{viewmodel.task}"
```

For this to work, `Task` needs to implement `CharSequence`. Using `viewmodel.task.toString()` might work as well. To implement a two-way-binding, you'd have to use `MutableLiveData` instead.

Comment: But Task is not just a string. Task is a full blown object with multiple properties. I understand that it's possible to bind to strings, booleans, ints etc. directly inside a LiveData, but then the viewmodel will be covered with livedata fields. I thought databinding was more mature and would be able to bind to the properties of the object inside a LiveData object. I'm going to add my Task class to my question.

Comment: I already have `binding.setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)` as this is inside a fragment.

Comment: THIS RIGHT HERE. Wow, I've been trying to fix for like 30 minutes. Thank you